# The derivative of $1 - e^{-t/\tau}$

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I am failing to understand how to compute the derivative of a few exponential functions.  Let's start with this one:

$$
v = 1 - e^{-t/\tau}
$$

The derivative is

$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1-v}{\tau}
$$

Can someone walk me through this?  If this is explained somewhere else, I'd love to know where.

Comment: \begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dt}&=\frac{1}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}\\
&=\frac{1}{\tau}(1-v)\\
&=\frac{1-v}{\tau}
\end{align}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} (1 - e^{-t/\tau}) &= -\frac{d}{dt}e^{-t/\tau} \\
&= - (-1/\tau) e^{-t/\tau} \\
&= \frac{e^{-t/\tau}}{\tau} \\
&= \frac{1 - (1 - e^{-t/\tau})}{\tau} \\
&= \frac{1 - v}{\tau}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\dfrac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1}{\tau} e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} = \frac{1-(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}})}{\tau}  = \frac{1-v}{\tau}$$. Is it clear?

Comment: I agree with @dbliss. Please elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dv}{dt}= \frac{d}{dt} (1 - e^{-t/\tau})$$

The derivative of $1$ is zero, so

$$= -\frac{d}{dt}e^{-t/\tau}$$

Using the chain rule,

$$= -e^{-t/\tau}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\frac{-t}{\tau}$$
$$= -e^{-t/\tau}\cdot\frac{-1}{\tau}$$
$$= \frac{e^{-t/\tau}}{\tau}$$

Now, we know that $v=1 - e^{-t/\tau}$. Rearranging gives $e^{-t/\tau}=1-v$. Substitute above to get

$$= \frac{1-v}{\tau}$$

Answer (score 0):

Derivative is a linear operator so it follows superposition:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(f(t)+g(t))=\frac{d f(t)}{dt}+\frac{d g(t)}{dt}$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dt}(k\times f(t))=k \times \frac{f(t)}{dt}~~~~~~~(k \text{ is constant number})$$

Also, derivative of some functions are known such as $\exp$, $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Putting all together, you can calculate derivative of this question.

In case a function derivative cannot be obtained by combinations of methods above, you need to use the general definition of derivation and solve a limit.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's walk:  first, note that

$v = 1 - e^{-t / \tau} \tag{1}$

yields, by direct differentiation, using the chain rule,

$\dfrac{dv}{dt} = -e^{-t / \tau} \dfrac{d(-t / \tau)}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{\tau} e^{-t / \tau}; \tag{2}$

from here on, it's simple algebra:

$\dfrac{1 - v}{\tau} = \dfrac{1 - (1 - e^{-t / \tau})}{\tau}$ $=\dfrac{1}{\tau} e^{-t / \tau} = \dfrac{dv}{dt}, \tag{3}$

using (2).  A pretty short walk, no?